# Percentage loader on ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I make file upload using the following. I want to show a progress bar displaying the percentage of the progress of file upload ?

```
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

and with ajax

```
  $.ajax({
                url: "/uploadImage",
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain : true,
                data: new FormData($("form")[0]),
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function( d) {
                     location.href="uploaddone.html";
                },
                error: function( d) {
                    location.href="Error.html";
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check this out, it has the information you'll need.  http://devpro.it/upload_progress/

Basically you need to keep checking the file size on the server vs the expected size to determine the percentage